# Trying to use JBoss WildFly 11, Hibernate 5.2, OGM 5 and MongoDB - EAR won't deploy

Tags: mongodb, hibernate-ogm, wildfly-11

Following the documentation:

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/ogm/reference/en-US/html_single/?v=5.3#ogm-gettingstarted

I am trying to use JPA OGM with MongoDB.

I have added the latest version of Hibernate ORM (5.2.14.Final) to the WildFly 11 module folder:

> /usr/local/Cellar/wildfly-as/11.0.0.Final/libexec/modules/system/layers/base/org/hibernate/5.2.14.Final

and downloaded and installed:

> hibernate-ogm-modules-5.3.0.Final-wildfly-11-dist.zip

However when I build and deploy the EAR I get:

```
18:34:16,467 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "NOTiFYwell.ear" (runtime-name: "NOTiFYwell.ear")
18:34:18,044 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYSRV0207: Starting subdeployment (runtime-name: "NOTiFYwellWAR.war")
18:34:18,044 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYSRV0207: Starting subdeployment (runtime-name: "NOTiFYwellJAR.jar")
18:34:18,515 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYJPA0002: Read persistence.xml for NOTiFYwellPersistenceUnit
18:34:18,516 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYJPA0002: Read persistence.xml for NOTiFYwellMongoDBPersistenceUnit
18:34:18,776 WARN  [org.jboss.modules] (MSC service thread 1-7) Failed to define class org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider in Module "org.hibernate:5.2.14.Final" from local module loader @6fffcba5 (finder: local module finder @34340fab (roots: /usr/local/Cellar/wildfly-as/11.0.0.Final/libexec/modules,/usr/local/Cellar/wildfly-as/11.0.0.Final/libexec/modules/system/layers/base/.overlays/layer-base-wildfly-11-weld-2.4,/usr/local/Cellar/wildfly-as/11.0.0.Final/libexec/modules/system/layers/base)): org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoadError: org.hibernate.jipijapa-hibernate5:5.2.14.Final
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoadException.toError(ModuleLoadException.java:74)
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.getPathsUnchecked(Module.java:1559)
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:708)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:412)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:400)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:116)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:358)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:437)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:274)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:77)
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:713)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:412)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:400)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:116)
    at org.hibernate.ogm.jpa.HibernateOgmPersistence.<init>(HibernateOgmPersistence.java:37)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.processor.PersistenceProviderHandler.deploy(PersistenceProviderHandler.java:74)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.processor.PersistenceBeginInstallProcessor.deploy(PersistenceBeginInstallProcessor.java:49)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:165)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:2032)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1955)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

18:34:18,777 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-7) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."NOTiFYwell.ear".FIRST_MODULE_USE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."NOTiFYwell.ear".FIRST_MODULE_USE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase FIRST_MODULE_USE of deployment "NOTiFYwell.ear"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:172)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:2032)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1955)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: WFLYJPA0019: Could not deploy application packaged persistence provider 'org.hibernate.ogm.jpa.HibernateOgmPersistence'
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.processor.PersistenceProviderHandler.deploy(PersistenceProviderHandler.java:79)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.processor.PersistenceBeginInstallProcessor.deploy(PersistenceBeginInstallProcessor.java:49)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:165)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.processor.PersistenceProviderHandler.deploy(PersistenceProviderHandler.java:74)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoadError: org.hibernate.jipijapa-hibernate5:5.2.14.Final
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoadException.toError(ModuleLoadException.java:74)
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.getPathsUnchecked(Module.java:1559)
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:708)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:412)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:400)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:116)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:358)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:437)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:274)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:77)
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:713)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:412)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:400)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:116)
    at org.hibernate.ogm.jpa.HibernateOgmPersistence.<init>(HibernateOgmPersistence.java:37)
    ... 12 more

18:34:18,781 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (External Management Request Threads -- 1) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "NOTiFYwell.ear")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"NOTiFYwell.ear\".FIRST_MODULE_USE" => "WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase FIRST_MODULE_USE of deployment \"NOTiFYwell.ear\"
    Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: WFLYJPA0019: Could not deploy application packaged persistence provider 'org.hibernate.ogm.jpa.HibernateOgmPersistence'
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    Caused by: org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoadError: org.hibernate.jipijapa-hibernate5:5.2.14.Final"}}
18:34:18,783 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (External Management Request Threads -- 1) WFLYSRV0021: Deploy of deployment "NOTiFYwell.ear" was rolled back with the following failure message: 
{"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"NOTiFYwell.ear\".FIRST_MODULE_USE" => "WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase FIRST_MODULE_USE of deployment \"NOTiFYwell.ear\"
    Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: WFLYJPA0019: Could not deploy application packaged persistence provider 'org.hibernate.ogm.jpa.HibernateOgmPersistence'
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    Caused by: org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoadError: org.hibernate.jipijapa-hibernate5:5.2.14.Final"}}
18:34:18,794 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYSRV0208: Stopped subdeployment (runtime-name: NOTiFYwellJAR.jar) in 11ms
18:34:18,798 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYSRV0208: Stopped subdeployment (runtime-name: NOTiFYwellWAR.war) in 14ms
18:34:18,812 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYSRV0028: Stopped deployment NOTiFYwell.ear (runtime-name: NOTiFYwell.ear) in 29ms
18:43:58,465 INFO  [org.jboss.as.repository] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 1) WFLYDR0009: Content /usr/local/Cellar/wildfly-as/11.0.0.Final/libexec/standalone/data/content/b4/f50292c0e75f0a407d46c7649f8f03c7c1b6a2 is obsolete and will be removed
18:43:58,471 INFO  [org.jboss.as.repository] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 1) WFLYDR0002: Content removed from location /usr/local/Cellar/wildfly-as/11.0.0.Final/libexec/standalone/data/content/b4/f50292c0e75f0a407d46c7649f8f03c7c1b6a2/content
18:43:58,471 INFO  [org.jboss.as.repository] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 1) WFLYDR0009: Content /usr/local/Cellar/wildfly-as/11.0.0.Final/libexec/standalone/data/content/06/38d1a6bf571ddafcba91ee07ca7051924973f7 is obsolete and will be removed
18:43:58,474 INFO  [org.jboss.as.repository] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 1) WFLYDR0002: Content removed from location /usr/local/Cellar/wildfly-as/11.0.0.Final/libexec/standalone/data/content/06/38d1a6bf571ddafcba91ee07ca7051924973f7/content
```

It appears to unable to load:

> Caused by: org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoadError:
>   org.hibernate.**jipijapa-hibernate5:5.2.14.Final**"}}

TIA.

Answer (score 0):

Did you update Hibernate ORM using the modules zip? https://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/hibernate/hibernate-orm-modules/5.2.14.Final/hibernate-orm-modules-5.2.14.Final-wildfly-11-dist.zip

That's where the missing module is.

Comment: I've rolled back to my pre ORM/OGM upgrades installation of WildFly 11. I did upgrade using the modules zip and have switched to ORM 5.2.14 JPA. Tested using MySQL   I think I missed something first time around. Now I have ORM 5.2.14 deployed & working going to add OGM 5.3. Thanks.